# Extract from string on varying conditions

Tags: r

I am trying to extract characters only and numbers only from a string. Because the positions of these vary, I can't use syntax which relies on the position of the values.

For example, say I have the following column x where values are repeated, but with different numbers:

```
x <- c("dummy.DR57", "dummy.hour41", "dummy.MAV43", "dummy.SB1")
```

I want to create two columns:
1: A column with just the characters after the "." but before the numbers:

```
name <- c("DR", "hour", "MAV", "SB")
```

2: A column with just the numbers:

```
number <- c("57", "41", "43", "1")
```

I've mostly been trying substr and str_sub - but I'm not getting the results I need.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x <- c("dummy.DR57", "dummy.hour41", "dummy.MAV43", "dummy.SB1")

(number <- gsub('[[:alpha:]].', '', x))
# [1] "57" "41" "3"  "1" 

(name <- gsub("[^.]*[.]|[[:digit:]]", "", x))
# [1] "DR"   "hour" "MAV"  "SB"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> gsub(x, pattern = '[0-9]|dummy\\.', replacement = '')
[1] "DR"   "hour" "MAV"  "SB"  
> gsub(x, pattern = '[a-zA-Z]|\\.', replacement = '')
[1] "57" "41" "43" "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
gsub(pattern = "(^.*\\.)([[:alpha:]]+)([[:digit:]]+)",
     replacement = "\\2",
     x = x)
# [1] "DR"   "hour" "MAV"  "SB"

gsub(pattern = "(^.*\\.)([[:alpha:]]+)([[:digit:]]+)",
     replacement = "\\3",
     x = x)
# [1] "57" "41" "43" "1"
```